# Prove invalid by backward and develop a model

Tags: logic, computer-science, predicate-logic

Prove this statement is invalid by backwards and develop a model which it's false

$$[\forall b~[\alpha(b) \to\forall a~\beta(a,b)]] \to [\alpha(1) \to \forall a\forall b~ \beta(a,b)]$$

I am kinda stuck on this and I hope someone could help. I know that we have to flip the whole thing backward and prove the right side equation is false but without knowing a and b relationship, I got stuck

Comment: Was that expression copied correctly; or is that indeed supposed to be $x$ and not $a$ ?

Comment: sorry it was supposed to be a

Comment: What does proving by backwards mean?

Answer (score 0):

Let domain $D=\{x \in \mathbb R: x \leq 1\}, \alpha=(b \geq 1)$, $\beta(a, b)=(a \leq b)$, then clearly under this model the antecedent of the whole implication is true, but the conclusion if false since $\alpha(1)=T$ while $\forall a \forall b~ \beta(a,b)=F$.